# Naive Bayse Classifier for Multiclass: Getting Same Error Rate

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I have implemented the Naive Bayse Classifier for multiclass but problem is my error rate is same while I increase the training data set. I was debugging this over an over but wasn't able to figure why its happening. So I thought I ll post it here to find if I am doing anything wrong.

```
%Naive Bayse Classifier
%This function split data to 80:20 as data and test, then from 80
%We use incremental 5,10,15,20,30 as the test data to understand the error
%rate. 
%Goal is to compare the plots in stanford paper
%http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-discriminativegenerative.pdf

function[tPercent] = naivebayes(file, iter, percent)
dm = load(file);
    for i=1:iter

        %Getting the index common to test and train data
        idx = randperm(size(dm.data,1))

        %Using same idx for data and labels
        shuffledMatrix_data = dm.data(idx,:);
        shuffledMatrix_label = dm.labels(idx,:);

        percent_data_80 = round((0.8) * length(shuffledMatrix_data));


        %Doing 80-20 split
        train = shuffledMatrix_data(1:percent_data_80,:);

        test = shuffledMatrix_data(percent_data_80+1:length(shuffledMatrix_data),:);

        %Getting the label data from the 80:20 split
        train_labels = shuffledMatrix_label(1:percent_data_80,:);

        test_labels = shuffledMatrix_label(percent_data_80+1:length(shuffledMatrix_data),:);

        %Getting the array of percents [5 10 15..]
        percent_tracker = zeros(length(percent), 2);

        for pRows = 1:length(percent)

            percentOfRows = round((percent(pRows)/100) * length(train));
            new_train = train(1:percentOfRows,:);
            new_train_label = train_labels(1:percentOfRows);

            %get unique labels in training
            numClasses = size(unique(new_train_label),1);
            classMean = zeros(numClasses,size(new_train,2));
            classStd = zeros(numClasses, size(new_train,2));
            priorClass = zeros(numClasses, size(2,1));

            % Doing the K class mean and std with prior
            for kclass=1:numClasses
                classMean(kclass,:) = mean(new_train(new_train_label == kclass,:));
                classStd(kclass, :) = std(new_train(new_train_label == kclass,:));
                priorClass(kclass, :) = length(new_train(new_train_label == kclass))/length(new_train);
            end

            error = 0;

            p = zeros(numClasses,1);

            % Calculating the posterior for each test row for each k class
            for testRow=1:length(test)
                c=0; k=0;
                for class=1:numClasses
                    temp_p = normpdf(test(testRow,:),classMean(class,:), classStd(class,:));
                    p(class, 1) = sum(log(temp_p)) + (log(priorClass(class)));
                end
                %Take the max of posterior 
                [c,k] = max(p(1,:));
                if test_labels(testRow) ~= k
                    error = error +  1;
                end
            end
            avgError = error/length(test);
            percent_tracker(pRows,:) = [avgError percent(pRows)];
            tPercent = percent_tracker;
            plot(percent_tracker)
        end
    end
end
```

Here is the dimentionality of my data

```
x = 

      data: [768x8 double]
    labels: [768x1 double]
```

I am using Pima data set from UCI

Comment: And btw: it is Bayes, not Bayse.

Answer (score 2):

What are the results of your implementation of the training data itself? Does it fit it at all?

It's hard to be sure but there are couple things that I noticed:

1. It is important for every class to have training data. You can't really train a classifier to recognize a class if there was no training data.
2. If possible number of training examples shouldn't be skewed towards some of classes. For example if in 2-class classification number of training and cross validation examples for class 1 constitutes only 5% of the data then function that always returns class 2 will have error of 5%. Did you try checking precision and recall separately?
3. You're trying to fit normal distribution to each feature in a class and then use it for posterior probabilities. I'm not sure how it plays out in terms of smoothing. Could you try to re-implement it with simple counting and see if it gives any different results?
4. It also could be that features are highly redundant and bayes method overcounts probabilities.